# LightningJs - Find if chart is ready

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have x and y data fetched via ajax , after I fetch I add series like below

```
series.add({ x: xVal, y: yVal})
```

But problem is out of 5 times , 3 times chart not loading. I think it is because I try to add series before chart is ready. Is there any callback to know if chart is ready and then I can add the x and y to series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as of now, LCJS renders synchronously with animation frames so you can find out when the Chart has rendered its first frame (and is pretty much "ready") with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

// ... Chart application code ...

// Get informed when Chart has rendered.
requestAnimationFrame( () => console.log('ready') )
```

But you really shouldn't need to wait for the Chart before adding data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no callback to know when the chart is ready.

The behavior you described shouldn't be possible, as long as you're always creating the chart first, before the series - and creating the series before adding a point to it.

Please make sure the order of creation is Chart -> Series -> Series.add